# docker image mesosphere/dcos-genconf not found

Tags: mesosphere, dcos

```
sudo bash dcos_generate_config.sh --web -v
```

Running `mesosphere/dcos-genconf` docker with `BUILD_DIR` set to `/home/ec2-user/genconf`

```
Unable to find image 'mesosphere/dcos-genconf:14509fe1e7899f4395-3a2b7e03c45cd615da' locally

Pulling repository docker.io/mesosphere/dcos-genconf
docker: Error: image mesosphere/dcos-genconf not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This used to happen when TERM, HUP or KILL were sent while dcos_generate_config.sh executed `docker load`. The latest EA (1.7) ships with a trap on those signals which cleans up in this event.

I'd suggest removing the dcos-genconf-$HASH.tar.xz which is written out to the directory in which you execute dcos_generate_config.sh, then re-running.

This way you're assured to not have a corrupted tar file or image. The image is a tar file appended after the EOF inside the dcos_generate_config.sh, it extracts that file, writes it to disk and then `docker loads` it. There's a lot that can go wrong with that methodology.

In line with removing that tar from disk I'd also recommend `docker rmi` on the image name if present before re-running.

Answer (score 4):

My guess you have a misconfigured Docker configuration. Can you please check what you changed from the default.

the image `mesosphere/dcos-genconf` is not on Docker Hub. It's inside of the script `dcos_generate_config.sh` the DC/OS installer unpacks it from a tar-file.

- Do you use a proxy configuration for the Docker Daemon?
- Is the file `dcos-genconf.14509fe1e7899f4395-3a2b7e03c45cd615da.tar` present in the directory `/home/ec2-user/`. Then delete the file.
- What is the output of `docker images`? Clean up all of your images that have the Repository `mesosphere/dcos-genconf`.

Then you can try again.

Comment: Deleting `dcos-genconf.14509fe1e7899f4395-3a2b7e03c45cd615da.tar` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `tar` file:

```
rm dcos-genconf.14509fe1e7899f4395-3a2b7e03c45cd615da.tar
```

and run again

```
bash dcos_generate_config.sh
```